# Which payment provider, such as PayPal, should I use for marketplace style site?

Tags: payments

Let's say I'm making a site similar to e-bay (connecting buyers and sellers). Which payment provider should I use as of today?

Comment: This question feels way too vague and subjective. If adamd has specific requirements then maybe it would be OK, but we don't want a hundred "what is the best [something]" questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) is a good shopping cart site.  They have a comprehensive list of payment processors, [here](http://www.shopify.com/faq/#third-party-processors), that can be used on any site, not just theirs.  I think your question is very broad though and I don't know what your goal is.  I think you should look into the providers below and which one fits you needs the best.

That being said, paypal is one of the best payment providers as far as rates go.  I have heard that people have fraud issues with them sometimes.

- http://www.authorize.net/ - Authorize.net
- http://www.beanstream.com - Beanstream
- http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com - Braintree
- http://www.cardstream.com/ - CardStream
- http://www.cybersource.com/ - CyberSource
- http://www.datacash.com/ - DataCash
- http://www.e-xact.com/ - E-xact
- http://www.concordefsnet.com/ - Efsnet
- http://www.elavon.com/ - Elavon MyVirtualMerchant
- http://www.instapayllc.com - InstaPAY
- http://www.linkpoint.com/ - Linkpoint
- http://merchantwarehouse.com/merchantware - MerchantWARE by Merchant Warehouse
- http://www.modpay.com - Modern Payments
- http://www.moneris.com/ - Moneris
- https://www.nelixtransax.com/ - NELiX TransaX
- http://www.netbilling.com - NETbilling
- http://www.netregistry.com.au - NetRegistry
- http://www.ogone.com/ - Ogone DirectLink
- http://www.paymentsolutionsltd.com/ - PSL Payment Solutions
- http://www.payjunction.com/ - PayJunction
- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside - PayPal Payflow Pro
- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside - PayPal Website Payments Pro (CA)
- https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside - PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK)
- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside - PayPal Website Payments Pro (US)
- http://www.commsecure.com.au/paysecure.shtml - PaySecure
- http://www.paymentexpress.com/ - PaymentExpress
- http://www.plugnpay.com/ - Plug'n Pay
- http://www.psigate.com/ - Psigate
- http://quickpay.dk/ - Quickpay
- http://www.realexpayments.com/ - Realex
- http://www.sagepayments.com - Sage Payment Solutions
- http://www.sagepay.com/ - SagePay
- http://www.securepay.com/ - SecurePay
- http://securepay.com.au/ - SecurePay (Australia)
- http://www.securepaytech.com/ - SecurePayTech
- http://www.skipjack.com/ - Skip Jack
- http://transfirst.com - TransFirst
- http://www.trustcommerce.com/ - Trust Commerce
- http://www.usaepay.com/ - USA ePay
- http://www.verifi.com/ - Verifi
- http://www.viaklix.com - ViaKLIX

Comment: That's all? <ducks>

Comment: @Tim - I thought I may as well be comprehensive!

Comment: Paypal is dead simple to integrate into a web site, there are plenty of scripts out there. I did this recently and amazingly it took half the time I expected it to.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Shopify. +1 I didn't know about them until I read your answer. Shopify might be exactly what a client of mine is looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alan - Your welcome. I know a number of people who really like shopify and I have heard nothing but good things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering adding off-site payment methods, consider how you are going to integrate these with your web analytics package - at the very least you are going to need to be able to tie the payment back to the originating session, so that you can incoming links (especially paid links) to revenue.

If the off-site payment process has more than a single page, have each step of the process tracked within your analytics package if at all possible. It's really helpful to be able to track how far along the payment process your users are reaching before bailing, to work out if there are UX problems preventing your users from giving you money.