# Website Form to deposit funds to your bank account

Tags: payments

Is there a way to receive payments to your bank account from your website.

I know PayPal is one option, and I know using a merchant account and gateway are another, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this answer, [Which payment provider, such as PayPal, should I use for marketplace style site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/which-payment-provider-such-as-paypal-should-i-use-for-marketplace-style-site/1477#1477) for a large list of payment providers found on the web.

You want to use one of these payment providers to transfer funds because the software is complex due to required security and the legal requirements that go along with creating a payment site.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1) Use a true merchant with payment gateway (if you are in the US)

2) Use a third party payment provider like Paypal

3) Use an ACH service like [Authorize.net's eChecks](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/echeck/)